# Fast way to format date: '2019-06-22D05:50:06.258066000'

Tags: python, pandas, date

My goal is to format strings(`'2019-06-22D05:50:06.258066000'`) to dates in dataframe timestamp column.
This is my idea, but it's very slow. Is there any faster solution?

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x:dt.datetime.strptime(x[:-10], '%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`?

Comment: was trying that also, but got error:
raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)

Comment: You can supply a format to the method (by the way your format is incomplete): `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format = '%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f')`. I've confirmed that this should work

Comment: Thx. Now I've got 2.841s for million rows. Earlier was  8.633s.